# How to make Laravel mobile app using build.phonegap.com

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm new to laravel. I want to develop a mobile app using Laravel(backend) and build it using build.phonegap.com site. Lately I have been searching tutorials about this but I don't want to use Angularjs as my frontend I just want to use html,css,js. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a way. But it would have to be purely a frontend application.

You build your app with Laravel as you would normally do and you create an API to interact with it using Javascript (jQuery, Angular, Vue...).

Creating an API for your app with Laravel is the easiest thing.

Once you have that, you can begin interacting with it through the mobile responsive design that you intend to use with `build.phonegap.com`

Comment: Thank you for the reply!. Yeah it's seems easy but the thing that is unclear to me is how to configure your laravel web app to be able to communicate with build.phonegap.com because when I read the documentation it says that you need a config.xml which is I don't know how to implement in my laravel app. If you know tutorials about this kindly send me links thank you!